# Partial DSC configuration for SMB

Tags: powershell, dsc

Unfortunately I can't find any examples on the internet for my scenario.

I got a DSC server with a SMB share. I want to deploy partial configs like in https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/dsc/pull-server/partialconfigs

But there are only examples for a HTTP DSC servers not SMB. Is this also possible with an SMB DSC server? If so, could I have an example?

Comment: Could you provide details of what you've tried so far? I'm not seeing anything that would prevent partial configurations from a SMB based pull server when I perused the page so more details on why it isn't working for you would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an example:

```
[DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
configuration PartialConfig
{
    Node localhost
    {
        Settings
        {
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
            ConfigurationID = 'a5f86baf-f17f-4778-8944-9cc99ec9f992'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }
           ConfigurationRepositoryShare SMBPull
        {
            SourcePath = '\\Server\Configurations'
            Name = 'SMBPull'
        }
           PartialConfiguration OSConfig
        {
            Description = 'Configuration for the Base OS'
            ConfigurationSource = '[ConfigurationRepositoryShare]SMBPull'
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
        }
           PartialConfiguration SQLConfig
        {
            Description = 'Configuration for the SQL Server'
            DependsOn = '[PartialConfiguration]OSConfig'
            RefreshMode = 'Push'
        }
    }
}
```